# Selenium Code works locally but not on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, pythonanywhere

I have a webscraper that is running on my system and I wanted to migrate it over to PythonAnywhere, but when I moved it now it doesn't work.

Exactly the sendkeys does not seem to work - after the following code is executed I never move on to the next webpage so an attribute error gets tripped.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time



# Lists for functions
parcel_link =[]
token = []
csv_output = [ ]

# main scraping function
def getLinks(link):


# Open web browser and get url - 3 second time delay.

#Open web browser and get url - 3 second time delay.
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(3)

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("mSearchControl_mParcelID")
inputElement.send_keys(parcel_code+"*/n")
print("ENTER hit")

pageSource = driver.page_source
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(pageSource)
parcel_link.clear()
print(bsObj)
#pause = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "mResultscontrol_mGrid_RealDataGrid")))

for link in bsObj.find(id="mResultscontrol_mGrid_RealDataGrid").findAll('a'):
    parcel_link.append(link.text)
print(parcel_link)

for test in parcel_link:
    clickable = driver.find_element_by_link_text(test)
    clickable.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

The link I am trying to operate is:
https://ascendweb.jacksongov.org/ascend/%280yzb2gusuzb0kyvjwniv3255%29/search.aspx

and I am trying to send: 15-100*

TraceBack:

```
03:12 ~/Tax_Scrape $ xvfb-run python3.4 Jackson_Parcel_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Jackson_Parcel_script.py", line 377, in <module>
    getLinks("https://ascendweb.jacksongov.org/ascend/%28biohwjq5iibvvkisd1kjmm45%29/result.aspx")
  File "Jackson_Parcel_script.py", line 29, in getLinks
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("mSearchControl_mParcelID")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 206, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"mSearchControl_mParcelID"}' ; Stac
ktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpiuuqg3m7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9470)
    at FirefoxDriver.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpiuuqg3m7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9479)
    at DelayedCommand.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpiuuqg3m7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11455)
    at DelayedCommand.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpiuuqg3m7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11460)
    at DelayedCommand.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpiuuqg3m7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11402) 
03:13 ~/Tax_Scrape $
```

Selenium Innitation:

```
for retry in range(3):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(3)

for parcel_code in token:
    getLinks("https://ascendweb.jacksongov.org/ascend/%28biohwjq5iibvvkisd1kjmm4 5%29/result.aspx")
```

PythonAnywhere uses a virtual instance of FireFox that is suppose to be headless like JSPhantom so I do not have a version number.

Any help would be great

RS

Answer (score 5):

Well, maybe the browser used on `PythonAnywhere` does not load the site fast enough. So instead of `time.sleep(3)` try [implicitly waiting](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#implicit-waits) for the element.

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
>   amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
>   not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the
>   implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

Using `time.sleep()` with `Selenium` is not a good idea in general.

And give it more than just `3` second, with `implicitly_wait()` you specify the *maximum time spent waiting for an element*. 
So if you set `implicitly_wait(10)` and the page loads, for example, in `5` seconds then `Selenium` will wait only `5` seconds.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```